# ILSpy decompile a delegate

Tags: .net, ilspy

ILSpy can decompile assemblies. Can it decompile a delegate? I would imagine a CSharpDecompiler constructor overload accepting a Func or an Action as an argument instead of a "string fileName". Is it technically feasible, are there any future plans to support this? Any suggested work-arounds?

Example of what I had in mind....

```
Action<int> myAction = i =>
{
    // body to be decompiled
};
var decompiler = new CSharpDecompiler(myAction, new DecompilerSettings());
decompiler.DecompileAsString();
```

Comment: What did you get when you tried it?

Comment: Can you have a compiled delegate outside of an assembly?

Comment: @phuzi no you cannot. What I had in mind is that I might have a delegate as a local variable and feed it to the decompiler without having to reference the assembly.

Comment: Your question would be a lot simpler to understand if you could provide some sample code *in your question*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An official ILSpy member has answered in the project's discussion section:

"It's not possible, because the decompiler requires a full PE image containing IL code and .NET metadata tables"

https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy/discussions/2581

Comment: Could you please provide the source of the quote?

Comment: @FelixQuehl https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy/discussions/2581

Comment: Great, thank you :)